# using Interop.outlook and ews

Tags: c#, outlook, interop, exchangewebservices

I am using EWS for searching for and displaying emails.  However the final step of the project is to save specific messages as .msg files on the file system.  I understand that this is not possible with EWS, so I will need to use Interop.Outlook to accomplish this.  My question is: What is the best way to find the Outlook message given the information available from EWS.  I have attempted to associate the Message.Id and ConversationId obtained from exchange via EWS with Outlook's messageId but have so far been unsuccessful.

Here is my current (failed) code for finding the ConversationID:

```
 OUTLOOK.Application olApp = new OUTLOOK.Application();
        OUTLOOK.NameSpace olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
        OUTLOOK.MAPIFolder oFolder = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(OUTLOOK.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
        OUTLOOK.Items oItems = oFolder.Items;
        String sFilter = string.Format("@SQL=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x1035001F\" = '{0}'", missive.ConversationID.UniqueId);
        object obj = oItems.Find(sFilter);
        OUTLOOK.MailItem oEmail = (OUTLOOK.MailItem)obj;
        if (oEmail != null)
        {
            return oEmail;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("MAIL ITEM NOT IN OUTLOOK");
        }
```

As a side:  I was looking for a reference for Outlookd filters  That is the property names for the [property]=value version; and the hex values for use with the @SQL version.  Does someone have a link to a good reference for that?

Answer (score 1):

There's a ConvertIdType request you can use; see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb856559(v=exchg.140).aspx.

For a listing of MAPI properties and their DASL names and property tag values, see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc815517.aspx.  Although Outlook Spy is a great tool for this as well.